How can I list users not active last 60 days with Azure KQL Query?
I am pretty limited in my knowledge of KQL, but i did in the past figure out how to run a KQL query in log analytics to give me the sign in logs for the users for the period of the last 60 days. This has been helpful, but I have been taking this list of users and in excel removing the users from the list of users from our security group to determine inactive users.
I am curious if there is a way in KQL to pull the list of users from security group we use, then pull the sign in log data and give me a list of the users that have not logged in 60+ days from today. I am not sure if this is possible.

Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to make an effort and show your code.

I can give you a brief idea of what steps can be used for example you gotta get users from the security group then get sign-in logs for the last 60 days and then perform a left anti join to find users who haven't signed in. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kusto/query/join-leftanti?view=microsoft-fabric for the leftantijoin details

This doc you can check once- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1265832/find-azure-users-who-have-not-signed-in-within-90 although not in KQL but maybe helpful for you


How can I list users not active last 60 days with Azure KQL Query?

Here is the KQL query to fetch the sign-in logs for users who have not logged in for more than 60 days. Follow the Stack link by Slavik N regarding the same requirement.

Note: For testing, I used 1 day, but you can set it to 60 days

SigninLogs
| extend d = parse_json(AuthenticationDetails)
| extend LoginTimestamp = todatetime(d[0].authenticationStepDateTime)
| where OperationName == "Sign-in activity"
| summarize max(LoginTimestamp) by AlternateSignInName, Identity
| where max_LoginTimestamp < ago(0d)
| distinct AlternateSignInName, Identity

Output:


if there is a way in KQL to pull the list of users from security group we use

There is no way to fetch the users in an Azure AD Group directly, but you can achieve this using the Azure Graph API. Follow the Stack  link by piovisqui.
Alternatively, you can use a PowerShell script for your requirement.


$kqlQuery = @"
SigninLogs
| extend d = parse_json(AuthenticationDetails)
| extend LoginTimestamp = todatetime(d[0].authenticationStepDateTime)
| where OperationName == "Sign-in activity"
| summarize max(LoginTimestamp) by AlternateSignInName, Identity
| where max_LoginTimestamp < ago(0d)
| distinct AlternateSignInName, Identity
"@


$workspaceId = "LAW-ID"  
$signInResults = Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId $workspaceId -Query $kqlQuery
$signInResults | Format-Table
$objId = "Azure-AD-Group-OBj-ID" 
$groupMembers = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objId | Select-Object DisplayName
$inactiveUsers = $signInResults | Where-Object { 
    $groupMemberNames -contains $_.Identity 
}
if ($inactiveUsers) {
    Write-Output "Users in the group who have not signed in for 0 days or more:"
    $inactiveUsers | Format-Table
    $inactiveUsers | Export-Excel -Path "C:\path\to\your\file.xlsx" -WorksheetName "InactiveUsers"

    Write-Output "Inactive users have been exported to Excel."
} else {
    Write-Output "No users in the group have been inactive for 0 days or more."
}


Note: In my case, I don't have 60 days of data, but you can set it to 60 if you have that data in your environment.

Output:


@IT4Gov, I hope this helps to resolve your problem?
